# How to use Keywords as Normal text in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, keyword

Is there a way to escape the keywords in mySQL. For instance, I want to add an alias name as 'AS'. mySQL is not allowing me to do that because AS is already a keyword.

In the below example, AS is the alias name for the table.
SELECT * FROM Astrology AS where AS.column_name is not null;

Note: I remember we use something like [AS] to treat them as normal text in MS-SQL. I would like to know how we could do this in mySql.

Comment: have you tried square brackets [AS] ?

Comment: @AmitVerma Only T-SQL (MS SQL Server and Sybase) uses `[]` for escapes. ISO SQL (which all RDMBS support, _aka_ ANSI SQL) uses double-quotes and should be the preferred way to escape names. As for MySQL, it uses backticks for escapes.

Comment: Or simply avoid choosing identifiers that are reserved words. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html contains the answer.

Comment: Thanks, backticks does the trick. Eg: SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;